# ubuntu software center not progress

Tags: software-center

There is a task in "progress Tab" of the Ubuntu software center: "searching canceling". It is in an infinite loop and I can not remove it. Also, I can not install new software because it is waiting for the above task to end. ???

Comment: What is the task? and how do you know it's an infinite loop? Some packages can take quite a while to be installed.

Comment: Since when & which package installation caused this , do a Reboot and try again.

Comment: Tried reboot, it's there foe a week... the package line just show: "Searching Cancelling"

Answer (score 0):

Kill Software Center and open it again. The broken task should die with it, and you can go back to using it normally.

Comment: I tried in terminal: sudo killall apt-get 
It didn't help?